# Can you help to secure the sky?

Tags: riddle, logical-deduction, cipher

You sit in an airplane high up in the sky, happy to be able to travel again. All of the sudden the man next to you dies. Don't panic! You see pen and paper on the tiny desk in front of him. There is a note:

```
011 110110110110 110 101 110110110 011 110 110011011 110011 110011110 011110110 110 110110110 110110110 101 110011011110 011011011 110110 110110110 011011011 011110 110 011110110 101 011011 110
```

Looks like binary. No. You believe you can read the message without knowing any binary. How? What does it say?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It reads

> *The stewardess poisoned me*,

so it's probably a suicide and an attempt to frame her, because how would he know that? Even more, why would he bother to write it in such a bizarre manner if he has just learned he's about to die soon?

The binary is actually

> a letter by letter substitution cipher, with "101" signifying a space.

Alternatively, you can

> replace every 110 with a dit, and every 011 with a dah, and read the morse code, which may or may not be quicker.

Comment: @Nati This is obviously the answer, so it's kind to accept it to show this puzzle is solved and give them some kudos :)